# Laravel sync hasMany with belongsTo array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Kind time of day everyone! The essence of my problem is this:
there are two models Contact and PhoneNum! relationships in models:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contacts';
    public function phoneNums()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PhoneNum');
    }
}
```

PhoneNum model

```
class PhoneNum extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'phoneNums';
    protected $fillable = ['phone_num'];

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Contact');
    }
}
```

In the form of editing contact, I get its name and an array with the phone numbers of this contact.

ContactController

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);
    $contact->name = $request->name;
    $contact->save();

    //what should I do with the array $request->phoneNums ????

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I can not synchronize these new phone numbers with a contact on id. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You must remove old contacts first and then insert the newly created.

```
$contact->phoneNums()->delete();
$contact->phoneNums()->saveMany([$request->input('phoneNums')]);
```

Comment: be aware of this.Updating using thing can make the old phonenums inaccessible with the relations

Answer (score 0):

First of all: change `$request->name` to `$request->input('name')`. With this change you'll know in about 5 months that this variable is coming from a form.

Second, the solutions to your problem. This is an example. You need to change it to the right names and add the variable to the mass assignment field in the model.

```
foreach($request->input('phoneNums') as $phoneNumber){
    $contact->phoneNums()->create([
        'number' => $phoneNumber
    ]);
}
```

And take a look at the PSR rules, so you can make your code more read-friendly: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/.

Answer (score -4):

Add sync method to update function as below

```
Public function update(Request $request, $id)

{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);
    $contact->name = $request->name;
    $contact->save();
    $contact->phoneNums()->sync($request->phoneNums, true)

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: `sync` works only with many-to-many associations. Question refers to one-to-many relationship.